# Can someone please explain this C++ output

Tags: c++

I have this c++ code and the output from the code. Can someone please tell me how this code is being iterated. I tried to dry run the flow but not able to figure out.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Something
{
public:
    Something(){cout<<"A\n";}
    virtual ~Something(){cout<<"B\n";}
};
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(){cout<<"C\n";}
    virtual ~Parent(){cout<<"D\n";}
};
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child(){cout<<"E\n";}
    Child(const Child& P){cout<<"F\n";}
    Child& operator=(const Child& rhs){cout<<"G\n";}
    virtual ~Child(){cout<<"H\n";}
protected:
    Something S_;
};
int main()
{
   Child ChildA;
   Child ChildB=ChildA;
   ChildA=ChildB;

   return 0;
}
```

Out:
C
A
E
C
A
F
G
H
B
D
H
B
D

Comment: This kind of thing has been explained many times. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Is there any particular part that you expect to be called in a different order?

Comment: Nothing is iterated, the code runs just once. This exercise is showing you when the class constructors and destructors get called, and in what order. Each cout<< statement is printing a unique letter, to help you see what order things are happening.

Comment: this type of questions always confuse me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a inheritance and composition:  child is a parent, and has a something.
Anyways, here's the use cases:

```
Child ChildA;
```

To make a child, you have to make a parent and a something.  There for you get:

> C A E

To make the second item, you're going to copy from `ChildA`, but you start out the same:  make a parent, make a something, then copy a child:

> C A F

Copy a value:

> G

Then destroy each from top down:

> H B D H B D

Comment: `Child` doesn't inherit from `Something`, it _contains_ a `Something`: `Child (contains Something) -> Parent`

Comment: @woolstar  Child& operator=(const Child& rhs){cout<<"G\n";} can you explain me this line please

Comment: I am basically stuck with the operator overloading at Child& operator=(const Child& rhs){cout<<"G\n";}  and also why is the sequence in which destructor are called.